# Templates for StackOverflow sub websites?

Tags: support

I was wondering.

Seeing that a lot of Stackoverflow websites like French language (http://french.stackexchange.com) are still using the "default" template, I was wondering how do you develop and present some kind of template for a website that still doesn't have its own template.

I do think most of it could be done with a CSS sheet, but where could a member turn it in for review to apply on a site?

Looking into what websites do have templates or not, it seems that all of them are in the beta stages. So the question might be more of where and when those templates are created and how could I give in my opinion on it, or participate into building it.

A followup would also be to propose a feature, making users able to choose to see the website in the template of their choice. Having, like most forums, 2-3 templates for members to choose from.

Comment: If you want to give your opinion, the per-site meta is the correct place to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Exchange [has an official designer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147574/jin).

Sites don't get their themes until they are ready to be launched.  At that point, Jin (the designer) will post a question on the per site Meta asking for feedback, posting a screenshot or otherwise demonstrating it.

The best way to contribute to it is to be check your sites Meta for that question when it comes, and post feedback and suggestions there.

I don't think the ability to customize how you view the site would be a good idea, because it's a lot of work for something that's only secondary (we're not here to look at the pretty pictures.  [Oh wait](https://photo.stackexchange.com/)).  Also, if you *really* want to, you can make userscripts to apply your own styles.

Comment: See also http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/our-designer-in-residence-jin-yang/

Comment: Regarding "if you really want to:" [userstyles](http://userstyles.org/) are probably an easier way to go (for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) or [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/?src=external-userstyleshome))